# Cloud Formation RDS "Specified OptionGroupName: devrdsoptiongroup not found"

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I'm working on a Cloud Formation template to restore an existing DB snapshot that looks something like this:

```
    "devDatabaseService" : {
       "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
       "Properties" : {
          "AllocatedStorage" : "200" ,
          "DBInstanceClass" : "db.m3.medium",
          "DBSnapshotIdentifier" : "snapshot-to-restor",
          "Iops" : 1000,
        "DBSubnetGroupName" : { "Ref" : "devDBSubnetGroup" },
          "Engine" : "sqlserver-se",
          "EngineVersion" : "11.00.2100.60.v1",
          "LicenseModel" : "license-included",
          "MasterUsername" : "admin",
          "MasterUserPassword" : { "Ref" : "DbPassword" },
          "StorageEncrypted" : "true",
          "Tags" : [ { "Key" : "Name", "Value" : "devDatabase" } ],
            "PubliclyAccessible" : true,
          "VPCSecurityGroups" : [ { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "devDBSecurityGroup", "GroupId" ] } ],
            "OptionGroupName": "devRDSOptionGroup"}
        }
        "DependsOn": "devRDSOptionGroup"
    },
    "devRDSOptionGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::RDS::OptionGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "EngineName" : "sqlserver-se",
        "MajorEngineVersion" : "11.00",
        "OptionGroupDescription" : "devRDSOptionGroup",
        "OptionConfigurations" : [],
        "Tags" : [ {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : "devRDSOptionGroup"} ]
      }
    }
```

Sadly, Stack creation fails with the error: "Specified OptionGroupName: devrdsoptiongroup not found"

If I create and reference a OptionGroup "manually" (e.g. through the console) it works just fine. I have also noticed that the OptionGroup is being created prior to attempting to create the DBInstance.

What Am I Doing Wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
"OptionGroupName": "devRDSOptionGroup"
```

to

```
"OptionGroupName": {"Ref" : "devRDSOptionGroup" }
```

I believe that the Name Tag that you're trying to put on the devRDSOptionGroup resource doesn't actually do anything - whereas if you reference the created resource, it should provide the name of your OptionGroup, per the AWS docs.